# Interactive Media Ads SDK for Flutter

Tags: flutter, imasdk

I am working on a Flutter application and I want to implement Google Interactive Media Ads SDK to Flutter. How do I implement IMA SDK in Flutter?

Comment: What have you did so far? Have you done any code? If so, add it to your question.

Comment: you would need your version of IMA sdk in DART I am guessing which is going to be super complicated. I would wait for something official from Google flutter team to come out.